# Formatting Some Data to Pass as Multi-Hyphenated String Names

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have some data formatting I need to do to create an array of elements I can pass. This is what I have:

```
// First I use `map` to create an array of just the job names:
jobList = dbJobs.map(job => job.attrs.name);

// Then I use `join()` to turn this into one long string
let jobListStr = jobList.join();

// Then I split this string into a new array, splitting on the comma
jobListArray = jobList.split(',');

// Then I need to add a hyphen between EACH of the words in each array element
// This is where the problem is. Here's what I tried:
for (let job of jobListArray) {
   job = job.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
}
```

What this does is LowerCase the text and successfully adds a colon between the first and second word in each element. But in a longer element - like `Job Something Else` this is problematic. Because obviously I need this result, where there is a hyphen between each word:

`job-something-else`

How can I resolve this last aspect?

To clarify, this is what my original data looks like:

```
[
  'Job Example One',
  'Job Example Two',
  'Job Example Three',
  'Job Something Else',
  'Job Yet Another Example'
]
```

And what I ultimately need is this:

```
[
  'job-example-one',
  'job-example-two',
  'job-example-three',
  'job-something-else',
  'job-yet-another-example'
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the formatting in the map:

```js
const dbJobs = [
  'Job Example One',
  'Job Example Two',
  'Job Example Three',
  'Job Something Else',
  'Job Yet Another Example'
]

const result = dbJobs.map(name => 
  name.toLowerCase() // convert the name to lower case
  .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // replace consecutive spaces with hyphens
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: In your case use `job.attrs.name`. If `name` is not a string, it doesn't have `toLowerCase` method.

Comment: Right, that just occurred to me.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks. I needed to target `job.attrs.name`. Then it worked. Many thanks, @Ori! Very succinct solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, replace function works differently. You will need to try the following to replace all spaces with a hyphen:

```
for (let job of jobListArray) {
   job = job.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
}
```